# sfp and sfp28 compatibility

Tags: broadcom

I have gotten a server which has "Broadcom 57454 10/25GbE SFP28 4-port OCP Ethernet Adapter" When I connect it to a switch port which is sfp the link status on the server is reported as active and it even sends packets for the DHCPDiscover but the packets never reach the server, the switch is unifi. The OS which I have tried is ubuntu18/Ubuntu22.10, right now I am trying freebsd 13, I load driver as a module at boot time I used loader.conf, I made following entry.

```
 if_bnxt_load="YES"
```

Is sfp28 backward compatible with sfp OR am I missing the driver for "Broadcom 57454 10/25GbE SFP28 4-port OCP Ethernet Adapter" which is causing the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

According to my testing sfp28 is compatible with sfp+ but it doesn't work with sfp.